# Get the entire Word document text into an array, split by newline

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to to get the total word document text into a variable and want to split the string into an array with newline as delimiter. How can I do that?

```
Dim str
str = ActiveDocument.?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this a *"doc"* file or a *"txt"* file?

something like this should work

```
Sub Test()
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split(ActiveDocument.Content.Text, Chr(13))
End Sub
```