# Find out if a word appears twice in X word radius

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to test if a word appears twice in a range of X (lets say for example 100) words.
If it does, the macro should highlight the word.

I've started with this loop:

```
For i = t To ActiveDocument.Content.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
```

Now I want to find and highlight words that appear twice in X (lets say 100) word radius.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of the `ComputeStatistics`, I'd collect all the words in the document into an array (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9450416/4717755) but split the words by a space). Then use your X radius to go forward and backward in the array to check for duplicates.

Comment: And this [Check if a given array contains duplicate elements within k distance from each other](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-given-array-contains-duplicate-elements-within-k-distance/) should help too. It has no VBA example but it shows the general idea/algorithm how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<(string to find)*\1>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) < 100 Then
      i = i + 1
      .Words.First.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
      .Words.Last.HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
    End If
    .End = .End - Len(.Words.Last)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found."
End Sub
```